# relative path or environment variable not works in /etc/xdg/autostart/?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, autostart

I make a auto-start script in /etc/xdg/autostart to make our product runs when boots.

the .desktop file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=autoStarter
Exec=sh /home/myname/Commands.sh
StartupNotify=false
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
Categories=System;Utility;Archiving;
Name[zh_TW]=hello.desktop
```

What I want to do is use the auto-starter to call a bash script in user's home file. In the Exec part, I always use absolutely path and it works fine. But I find that I'm not able to change the absolutely path to relative path.

I tried these:

```
Exec= sh ~/Commands.sh
Exec= sh $HOME/Commands.sh
Exec= sh /home/$USER/Commands.sh
```

not worked

all of these commands work in terminal but fail when I put them to *.desktop file

what should I do?

Comment: `sh -c '~/Commands.sh'`, or `sh -c '$HOME/Commands.sh'`, assuming the scripts are executable.

Comment: thank you for your response. I find that if I want to use sh command i have to re-write it again, so the command would like  `sh -c ' sh ~/Commands.sh'`

Comment: Then your script is probably not executable. `chmod +x` should fix that.